# Stuck with scanf in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly and made a program which will read values from keyboard . I used scanf function for this purpose .I am calling scanf function in loop so as I can input multiple values.But issue is I am not able to limit values entered by the keyboard.Below is the code

Now I wanted to input four values from scanf but it keep on asking the values from user.

```
  section .bss
  c1 dd
  b dd
  section .data
  x db "%d",10,0
  y db "number is =%d",10,0
  section .text
global main
extern printf
extern scanf


main:
mov edx,0
loop_done:
mov [b],edx
lea ebx ,[c1]
push ebx
push x
call scanf
mov edx,[b]
push dword [c1]
cmp edx,3
inc edx
jnz loop_done
push y
call printf


add esp,16

ret
```

Comment: Why-oh-why does everyone who is "new to assembly" want to jump right into mixed-language assembly plus C library plus the whole compiler/platform-specific language ABI morass? It seems to me it would be better to learn assembly well first, then figure out how to interface with other languages/libraries/ABIs...

Comment: Well You may be right @twalberg ,don't know how to learn assembly ,what I thought was I should go make assembly programe equivalent to C .If you do have other some approach to learn assemblty would be great if you let us know .

Answer (score 1):

You're not reserving enough space for `b` and `c1`. `dw` only reserves a 16-bit word, but since you're storing 32-bit dwords you need to use `dd`. What currently happens when `scanf` writes the read value to `c1` is that it overwrites `b` (where you have stored the value of `edx`, i.e. your loop counter).

Comment: So @Micheal should I comment mov edx,[b] or what??

Comment: No. Like I said in my answer, you need to use `dd` instead of `dw`. One thing you should remove though is the `push dword [c1]` since it doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: Yes Micheal ,I did what you suggested (used dd insted of dw in .bss section) but still facing the same issue.

Comment: You should update your question with the actual code that you're compiling. The one that you've posted now doesn't look like it would assemble due to a typo (`ea ebx ,[c1]`).

Comment: You're not balancing the stack correctly. You push 12 bytes every iteration of the loop, but you're only popping 16 bytes at the very end. So the `ret` would probably return to the wrong location. Also, you're doing `cmp` and `inc` in the wrong order (the result of `inc` will always be non-zero, except in the case where the old value of the operand was -1). You really should use a debugger to step through your program, since most of these bugs would then become obvious.

Comment: Yes Michael , Since I'm new to assembly really not sure how to use debugger but surely will try to use some debugger.Thanks for your response once again

Comment: @Micheal just wanted to update ,changing edx to ebp worked for me,though still getting some segmentation fault after getting three values from user

Answer (score 0):

This is how I change my code to work well,Please do correct me if something is going below in the code.

```
section .bss
c1 dd
b dd
section .data
x db "%d",10,0
y db "number is =%d",10,0
section .text
global main
extern printf
extern scanf


main:
mov edx,1
loop_done:
push edx
;mov [b],edx
lea ebx ,[c1]
push ebx
push x
call scanf
add esp,8
pop edx
;mov edx,[b]


;mov ecx,[c1]
;ush dword [c1]
;mov edx,[b]
 inc edx
 cmp edx,4

 jnz loop_done
 ;add esp,8

  ret
```